# load GeoRSS from geoserver to OpenLayer

Tags: geoserver

```
var value = GEOSERVERBASE + '/geoserver/tiger/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=tiger:poi&styles=&bbox=-74.0118315772888,40.70754683896324,-74.00153046439813,40.719885123828675&width=427&height=512&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application%2Frss%2Bxml';
var georss = new OpenLayers.Layer.GeoRSS('Tiger POI', value);
map.addLayer(georss);
```

This is the code on one book, however it's not working. The data is indeed there. but it doesn't load. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what you are putting in your value variable doesn't look correct to me for getting GeoRSS out of Geoserver. Instead try something like

```
var value = GEOSERVERBASE + '/geoserver/wms/reflect?layers=tiger:poi&format=rss'
```

or

```
var value = GEOSERVERBASE + '/geoserver/wms?layers=tiger:poi&format=rss'
```

Depening on your Geoserver version or configuration

As you can see I have changed the format to just rss rather than what you originally had.

If that works then I would start adding in the other options like bounding boxes ect.